# event.target.id not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cross-browser

I have a script that gets run every time a user hovers over one of my page buttons. This works great in safari and chrome, but in firefox the event.target.id is being returned null so the rest of my script can't run. At first I thought it was a problem with mouseenter, but I added an alert to my function and it got fired so it is being triggered. The console shows event.target.id as empty and that's the problem.

Anyone have a fix? This grabs the id of the button the user hovers over, and sets the body of the page equal to the html of the hidden div with the same class as the button's id.

```
$(".label").mouseenter(function(){
   var hover=(event.target.id);
   $('.centercover').fadeIn(400)
   var filler= $('.'+hover).html();
   ....rest of script for fadding in new content...
   }
```

Comment: You need to declare the event argument in the function. `$(".label").mouseenter(function(event){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".label").on('mouseenter', function(event){ //pass the parameter
   var hover = event.target.id;
   $('.centercover').fadeIn(400)
   var filler = $('.' + hover).html();

});
```

Comment: I'm sure he is doing that, otherwise, it wouldn't work anywhere around like the OP stated.

Comment: @jAndy: The other browsers may still have a global `event` variable for IE compatibility